# How can I reduce the size of a whole equation without reducing the size of its numbering?

Tags: math-mode, equations, cross-referencing, amsmath, mathtools

I have an equation that I need to reduce its size but it seems that the equation numbering gets smaller as well. How can I reduce its size while having normal size for its tag?

[image]

My source code:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsfonts}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand {\arraystretchdefaultl} {1.3}
\newcommand{\arraystretchdefault}{ \renewcommand {\arraystretch} {\arraystretchdefaultl} }
\arraystretchdefault

\usepackage{makecell}


\begin{document}


\begin{equation}
\scriptsize
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
V_{i} \\ \midrule[0.25mm]
0
\end{array}
\right]
%
=
%
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.6}
\left[
\begin{array}{c c !{\vrule width 0.25mm}c c}
& Z_{orig} &  & col. \medspace k - col. \medspace p \\ \Xcline{1-4}{0.25mm}
& row. \medspace k - row. \medspace p & & Z_{th,kp}+Z_{b}\\
\end{array}
\right]
%
\arraystretchdefault
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
I_{i} \\ \midrule[0.25mm]
I_{q}
\end{array}
\right]
\end{equation}


\begin{equation}
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
V_{i} \\ \midrule[0.25mm]
0
\end{array}
\right]
%
=
%
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.6}
\left[
\begin{array}{c c !{\vrule width 0.25mm}c c}
& Z_{orig} &  & col. \medspace k - col. \medspace p \\ \Xcline{1-4}{0.25mm}
& row. \medspace k - row. \medspace p & & Z_{th,kp}+Z_{b}\\
\end{array}
\right]
%
\arraystretchdefault
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
I_{i} \\ \midrule[0.25mm]
I_{q}
\end{array}
\right]
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: To make the first larger use `\tag*{\refstepcounter{equation}\normalsize(\theequation)}`.  To make the second smaller use `\tag*{\refstepcounter{equation}\scriptsize(\theequation)}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since your question is not clear to me, i only suspect that you looking for something like this:

[image]

for above equations i remove all unnecessary columns in `array`s, reduce `\arraycolsep` and simplify use of `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{...}`. i also replace `equation` with `gather` math environment:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{array, makecell}
    \setlength\arraycolsep{3pt}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}

\begin{document}
    \begin{gather}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.6}
\left[\begin{array}{c}
V_{i}   \\
\Xcline{1-1}{0.25mm}
0
\end{array}\right]
=
\left[\begin{array}{c !{\vrule width 0.25mm} c }
                    Z_{orig}    & \text{col. } k - \text{col. } p   \\
    \Xcline{1-2}{0.25mm}
\text{row. } k - \text{row. } p & Z_{th,kp}+Z_{b}
\end{array}\right]
%
\left[\begin{array}{c}
I_{i} \\
\Xcline{1-1}{0.25mm}
I_{q}
\end{array}\right]
                            \\
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.6}
\left[\begin{array}{c}
V_{i} \\
\Xcline{1-1}{0.25mm}
0
\end{array}\right]
=
\left[\begin{array}{c !{\vrule width 0.25mm} c}
                    Z_{orig}    & \text{col. } k - \text{col. } p \\
\Xcline{1-2}{0.25mm}
\text{row. } k - \text{row. } p & Z_{th,kp}+Z_{b}
\end{array}\right]
%
\left[\begin{array}{c}
I_{i} \\
\Xcline{1-1}{0.25mm}
I_{q}
\end{array}\right]
    \end{gather}
\end{document}
```

note: `amssymb` package (now) contain `amsfonts`, so it is not need to load it again.

Comment: I did not know that `\arraycolsep` is a parameter that could be used to customize arrays. This is equivalent to `\tabcolsep` parameter. It seems that `array` environments can take most of what `tabular` environments take

Comment: @Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh, your observation/conclusion is correct :-).